# Using drop shadows from Sketch in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have a rectangle in Sketch that has shadows with these properties:

- X: 0
- Y: 16
- Blur: 24
- Spread: 0
- RGBA: 0,0,0,3

In Sketch, this yields a rectangle with shadows on each side:

- Top: 8px
- Bottom: 40px
- Left: 24px
- Right: 24px

I'm not sure how I could achieve a rectangle with these shadows in Android.

In Sketch:

[image]

Comment: Dropshadows are actually not supported by Android (and elevation is a trap), but you can try your luck with http://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Does that generate code or just an image?

Comment: It generates a 9-patch drawable (stretchable image)